# Using fprintf in for loop provides wrong values

Tags: matlab

I'm have a MATLAB function file which calculates error values for a given function. I'm currently doing this for 3 iterations individually by going

```
k=[5,10,15];

% Iteration 1
error1= (vel(5,t1,t2,func)-exact)*100/exact;

% iteration_2
error2 = (vel(10,t1,t2,func)-exact)*100/exact;

% iteration_3
error3 = (vel(15,t1,t2,func)-exact)*100/exact;

fprintf("Error for k = 5, error1 = %0.4f \nError for k = 10, error2= %.4f \nError for k = 15, error = %.4f\n ",error1,error2,error3)
```

I attempted to get this into a for loop using this

```
for i = 1:length(k);
K = k(i);
error = vel(k,t1,t2,func);
error(i) = error;
error = abs((error-exact)/exact);
fprintf('Error for %d is %0.4d\n',K,error)
end
```

However when I try to run this for loop, my fprintf is completely wrong. I've been trying to get it working for a while now but it's still giving me wrong answers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Don't use `error` as a variable name. It's a useful function that you're hiding. Syntax highlighting should warn you to this. What did you expect `error(i) = error;` to do?

Comment: Thanks, I changed the variable name. I wanted error(i)=error; to get the values from the error = vel(k,t1,t2,func); and store them into the matrix called 'error'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
k=[5,10,15];
for i=k
    error=abs(vel(i,t1,t2,func)-exact)/exact*100;
    fprintf('Error for %d is %.4f\n',i,error);
end
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you! Also, do you know if it's possible to store each value for the error into a new matrix, e.g. A matrix iter_matrix=['value for error1'. 'value for error2'. etc.]

Comment: Of course. Replace each `error` with `error(i)`. And put `error=zeros(1,numel(k));` just before the `for` statement.

Comment: Thank you, this stores the values for the error in a 1x15 double matrix where every value between 5,10,15 is 0. How would I go about making it only store the values where an answer exists? i.e. the matrix stores the values from the results of i=5,10,15 so it would be a 1x3 matrix instead.

Comment: Oh that was my mistake. So starting from the answer. Replace each `error` with `error(n)`. And put `error=zeros(1,numel(k)); n=0;` just before the `for` statement. And `n=n+1;` just after the `for` statement.

Comment: Thank you so much, also I tried to plot k vs error and it gives a line connecting the values. Do you know if there's a way that shows each individual data point as a dot but keeps the line going through all 3 points? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Nevermind, got it using the method you taught me before.
I went:

'iter=0;
for i=K
iter=iter+1;
scatter(k(iter),val_error(iter))
end`